# Sum of selected columns filtered by regex in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Well, I do understand that gnuplot is not a data-processing system but a plotting software. But anyway...

In python-pandas, I can select multiple columns by passing a [regex to dataframe](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) e.g. `df.filter( regex = '\.x$' )` will return columns named 'sw0.x', 'sw1.x' etc. Then I can sum them up and plot them.

Recently I've moved to `pgfplots` (latex) and I use gnuplot extensively with pgfplots on large-data set. Many times I needs to plot the sum of many columns which matches a given regular expression. I want to do something like `plot 'data.csv' SUM("\.x$") every 100 with line` where function/macro/whatever `SUM` accepts the regular expression and returns me the sum of appropriate columns.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, it will be most likely necessary to "outsource" this processing part to Pandas. For example if you create a script `filter.py` such as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd
import sys

df = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1], sep = ',', header = 0)
s = df.filter(regex='\.x$', axis = 1).sum(axis = 1)
s.to_csv(sys.stdout, sep = '\t')
```

then you can "reuse" it in Gnuplot as:

```
plot "<python filter.py data.csv" w lp
```

Answer (score 0):

gnuplot does not support regular expressions, but in some cases you can get similar functionality by defining suitable functions.
@Dilawar, you don't give too much details about your data. I assume separator is whitespace.
As @ewcz wrote, you can always use external tools to (pre-)process your data into such a format that gnuplot can plot it.
However, if possible and if it is not getting too complicated why not using gnuplot itself?

In your case you're asking about summing up columns if the end of the columnheader matches a certain string. Check the example below which can certainly be optimized further.

**Script:** (*revised and simplified version*)

```
### select columns by matching end of columnheader
reset session

$Data <<EOD
ID sw0.x sw0.y sw0.z sw1.x sw1.y sw1.z
1    0.1   1.1   3.1   0.2   1.2   3.2
2    0.2   1.2   3.2   0.3   1.3   3.3
3    0.3   1.3   3.3   0.4   1.4   3.4
4    0.4   1.4   3.4   0.5   1.5   3.5
EOD

set datafile separator "\t"
stats $Data u (myHeaders=strcol(1)) every ::0::0 nooutput 
set datafile separator              # restore to default
myHeader(i) = word(myHeaders,i)     # get the ith item of the header line
colMax = words(myHeaders)

matchEnd(s,m) = s[strlen(s)-strlen(m)+1:strlen(s)] eq m    # 1=match, 0=no match
sumUp(m)      = sum [col=1:colMax] ( matchEnd(myHeader(col),m) ? column(col) : 0 )
myMatches     = ".x .y .z"
myMatch(i)    = word(myMatches,i)
set key out

plot for [i=2:colMax] $Data u 1:i w lp pt 6 ti columnhead, \
     for [i=1:words(myMatches)] '' u 1:(sumUp(myMatch(i))) \
         w lp pt 7 ps 2title sprintf("Sum up %s",myMatch(i))
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]